# How does Namenode decides in which datanode to write a block

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I was just wondering about this. Suppose I am copying a 80 GB file to HDFS and my block size is 64 MB. Now after gathering data worth of a block, the namenode writes the block to a datanode. Here is my question: In what fashion the namenode selects to which datanode the block should be written into. Is it a random selection or some round robin selection?

Answer (score 2):

NameNode will select blocks on datanode based on the load distribution factor. It will select blocks in such a way that the load on all running datanodes is balanced out.

Also, the NameNode does not `gather data worth of a block and write it to a datanode`. When a write request is sent to the NameNode, it assigns the blocks to be written on the respective datanodes, and then instructs the dataNodes to begin copying the data from the source. It is a master node; it does not do the copying itself.

Comment: Thanks @chaos. Can you give me some insight on the load distribution factor. Or may be some links so that I can get some help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a good question is when NN is making the decision, does it decide based on disk percentage on the DN or absolute size?
say I have 2 datanode with 10TB and 1TB disk. will it balance based on percentage or size. if latter one is chosen, that means 1TB datanode will be filled to 100% before the 10TB is even barely used.